# How to get the custom field value using SQL query

Tags: plugins, custom-post-types, php, plugin-development, mysql

I am using the WordPress and I have created a custom post type. Also, I have added the custom field for each custom post.

Now I have to fetch the data from the database and I tried the below query

```
SELECT p.ID, 
       p.post_date, 
       pm.meta_key,
       pm.meta_value
FROM wp_posts p 
   INNER JOIN wp_postmeta pm 
       ON p.ID = pm.post_id
WHERE p.post_type = 'test'
   AND p.post_status = 'publish'  and p.ID=972
```

The above query is working and I am getting the below output. (It's just an example of the screenshot.)

[image]

Now my issue is, Is it possible using a query to get the only `dropboxlink2` and `dropboxlink3` values? As of now I am getting all the custom post field list

**Note: I know how to get in the WordPress but I need a solution in PHP and MySQL**

Comment: Plain SQL questions are off topic here. You should ask on stackoverflow.com

Comment: ok. let me delete this question

Comment: @NarenVerma if you provide some background perhaps there are alternatives or shortcuts that don't involve pure SQL that might even be faster

Comment: @TomJNowell, Actually I have a PHP page and I have to show that information on that page.

Comment: Then there are lots of alternatives, such as bootstrapping WP and using the WordPress functions directly, or grabbing the post and its data via the REST API

Comment: @TomJNowell, I have one doubt but not related to this question. My doubt is, I have created a one file called process.php in my theme and I added my all the insert, update, delete code and it's working. Now If I add any WordPress function like get_posts, get_categories etc. in process.php then that is not working. I was getting the WordPress database error:

Comment: that's to be expected, those functions only work normally because WordPress loaded the file, you can't load the file directly and expect it all to magically work out of the box. In general, loading a PHP file in a theme or plugin directly in the browser is a security risk and not good practice, it should be avoided. If you need to process a form, handle an AJAX request, or expose data in WordPress there are much better ways to do that

Comment: @TomJNowell, Ok I got your point, I have to use the function.php file and add all the logic code there itself.